# @mailer and @twig in argument of a service error ServiceCircularReferenceException

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to put twig like argument of my service but i have always the same error :

**ServiceCircularReferenceException in bootstrap.php.cache line 2129**

*Circular reference detected for service "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager",path: "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager -> doctrine.dbal.default_connection -> wh.participant_listener -> wh.participant_notification -> twig -> security.authorization_checker -> security.authentication.manager -> fos_user.user_provider.username -> fos_user.user_manager".`*

This is my service.yml file

```
wh.participant_notification:
    class: WH\TrainingBundle\Notification\Notification
    arguments: [@mailer, @twig]

wh.participant_listener:
    class: WH\TrainingBundle\EventListener\ParticipantListener
    arguments: [@wh.participant_notification]
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postUpdate }
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }
```

My PartcicipantListenerFile

```
namespace WH\TrainingBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use WH\TrainingBundle\Notification\Notification;

class ParticipantListener
{


    protected $notification;

    public function __construct(Notification $notification)
    {
        $this->notification = $notification;

    }


}
```

This probleme exist only when i pass @wh.participant_notificationin arguments of my second service

Any body has an idea ?

Thank's a lot

Answer (score 2):

I've find a solution, not pretty, but it works :

First i pass the service container in argument of my service

```
services:

wh.participant_notification:
    class: WH\TrainingBundle\Notification\Notification
    arguments: ['@service_container']

wh.participant_listener:
    class: WH\TrainingBundle\EventListener\ParticipantListener
    arguments: ['@wh.participant_notification']
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }
```

then in my Notification.php class :

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;

private $container;

public function __construct(Container $container) {

    $this->container = $container;

}

public function subscribValidation ($participant) {

    $templating = $this->container->get('templating');
    $mailer = $this->container->get('mailer');

    ...
```

I can't create protected var $twig because the probleme persiste. 
I repeat, its only with twig service (or template). 
Maybe another one find a better solution ...

Comment: Indeed, the very cause is the declaration of both $mailer and $templating as protected properties of the listener.

Answer (score 0):

The circular message, while unclear, should guide you.

Doctrine entity manager loads its listeners,`wh.participant_notification` among them. Your service requires `twig` which in turns requires a chain of other things, doctrine entity manager among them. This causes the exception above.

One solution to this issue could be to use [setter injection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/types.html#setter-injection)

So you can just define your service as:

```
wh.participant_notification:
  class: WH\TrainingBundle\Notification\Notification
  calls:
    - [setMailer, ["@mailer"]]
    - [setTemplating, ["@templating"]]
```

and add to your Notification class the setter methods

```
class Notification
{
  private $mailer;
  private $templating;

  public function setMailer(\Mailer $mailer)
  {
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
  }

  public function setTemplating(\Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine $templating)
  {
    $this->templating= $templating;
  }

  ...your code...
```

Comment: - [setTemplating, ["@twig"]]

    public function setTemplating(\Twig_Environment $twig)
    {
        $this->template = $twig;

    }

Comment: Yes, you should add both setters ;)

Comment: Hey @Jerome I just expanded my answer. You should probably inject `templating` as service, not `twig`. And `TwigEngine` is probably the right choice, not `Twig_Environment`.

Comment: (v 2.8.4-DEV) even the setter injection (as described here) keep on raising circular reference